# Live agent deployment API: chat end callback

Tags: api, liveagent

I'm using Deployment API to start the chat. Is there any way to know when the chat ends? I'd need to perform some action on the site when user finishes the chat, so a callback would be really useful here.

Answer (score 2):

When your chat ends, the `saveToTranscript()` method is triggered  so you can use that to do post chat processing.

Something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="Case" />
```